# can json_encode( ... ) ever return false with an array?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am writing some phpunit tests to check a custom json class I wrote.

I have some code I would like to test...

```
...
$contents = json_encode( $data );
if( false === $contents )
{
  ...
}
...
```

But if '$data' is an array it never returns false, even if I pass some invalid parameters the result is something along the line of

```
{null:null}
```

How can I test encode_json( ... ) returning false when I pass an array?

Comment: you can try to mock the behaviour of the `json_encode` function with [this](https://github.com/tcz/phpunit-mockfunction) phpunit extension that use uses runkit

Answer (score 4):

Check out the PHP documentation for `json_last_error()`: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

It has an example which causes `json_encode()` to fail, which I have adapted here to use an array for demonstration purposes:

```
<?php
// An invalid UTF8 sequence
$text = ["text" => "\xB1\x31"];

$json  = json_encode($text);
$error = json_last_error();

var_dump($json, $error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
?>
```

When running this, I get this expected result, indicating a `json_encode` error:

```
$ php php-test.php 
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Comment: That's a string, not an array as in my question, try and encode ["\xB1\x31" => "\xB1\x31" ] and it does not return false.

Comment: No, as I mentioned in my question, it is a custom class.
But regardless, the question still stands, how can it return false with an array, (as it does with a string for example).

Comment: this test is passing for me: public function testJsonEncodeReturnFalse()
    {
        $data = array("\xB1\x31" => "\xB1\x31");
        $contents = json_encode( $data );
        $this->assertFalse($contents);
    }

Comment: really?, what version of php are you using? I get {null:null} with the exact same test. I am using 5.4.8 in my dev environment, (yes I know it is close to eol, but still).

Comment: Hi @FFMG i use a 5.5.x i tested on a 5.4.x and work as you described. I don't know why. Hope this help.

Comment: your $text string will not return false. tried this and I am not able to get a false from json_encode()

Comment: With version 5.6 I get the same results as @Jeff